Difference between "to fall by 50 per cent" and"to fall at 50 per cent"
What is the difference between these 2 sentences?

The price fell by 50 per cent

The price fell at 50 per cent


Thank you in advance!

"The price fell at 50 per cent" is not idiomatically valid, so it's anybody's guess what someone might mean by using it.


"The price fell by 50 per cent" is clear and is a common pattern. The price was reduced to 50% of a previous value, e.g. from $100 to $50.

"The price fell at 50 per cent" is less clear. If it is intended to have the same meaning, it is not an idiomatic choice. I'm not sure I could give an example of a context in which it would be a good choice. Perhaps one might encounter it if we were tracking another kind of data besides price, like market volume, and when that measurement reached 50%, the price fell.


You didn't ask about it, but I'll also mention "The price fell to 50%." The point of this one is that it says where the price ended, without specifying what it was before. E.g. if I reduced the price to 75% of the original, and the item didn't sell for a week so I reduced it again to 50%, then I can't say "today the price fell by 50%"; today's reduction was less. But I can say "today the price feel to 50% of the original."

Thank you a lot!!
